# Tools for parsing automatically-generated HTTP indexes?

Tags: wget

Web servers commonly generate directory indexes listing the files within a directory and additional metadata.  There is variation in the content and formatting of these pages, but generally have a strong common resemblance.

There are common operations like identifying the most recent file in a directory according to the listed timestamp or downloading the file with latest version.  These involve common steps of downloading the html index, extracting filenames, pattern-matching, date parsing, sorting, etc...  I typically hack together a minimal solution in bash using wget, grep, awk, sort, and date, but I'm curious if anyone has worked on generalized solutions to problems involving html file indexes.

**Are there any (preferably command-line) utilities for processing/parsing these html files?**

Obviously it is a non-trivial task and can't be performed perfectly by in all cases, but a solution that avoids re-implementing the wheel for 90% of all cases is certainly within the realm of possibility.

Comment: Sounds like you want a spider. I've had good experiences with  [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you mean is you want to parse the HTML contained in the HTTP response.
If you are familiar with PHP you could use curl to retrieve the page then parse the string into its DOM structure using PHP's [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#class.domdocument), then you can retrieve the innerHTML of interest by querying the DOMDocument instance.
As a commandline PHP script

```
#!/usr/bin/php

// curl or readfile or whatever for url and assign HTML body into variable $html
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    link
</head>
<body>
    <h1>stuff in directory listing</h1>
</body>
</html>
';

$DOM = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);

$element = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("h1")->item(0);
echo $element->nodeValue;
```

Thats how I would do it anyway, and the reason is because

1. it would give a flexible implementation, where you can adapt to the different responses webservers would give you.
2. trying to parse content by regex would be really hard (Im guessing)

Here is a **demo** - http://codepad.viper-7.com/apsiKR